# Node xlsx module get headers of the excel file

Tags: node.js, excel, xlsx

How to get the headers of the given Excel file in node xlsx (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I could find, there's no exposed method to get headers of the Excel file from the module. So I copied few functions (With all respect to author. https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)  from their source code and make that work with few changes.

```
function getHeaders(sheet){
    var header=0, offset = 1;
    var hdr=[];
    var o = {};
    if (sheet == null || sheet["!ref"] == null) return [];
    var range = o.range !== undefined ? o.range : sheet["!ref"];
    var r;
    if (o.header === 1) header = 1;
    else if (o.header === "A") header = 2;
    else if (Array.isArray(o.header)) header = 3;
    switch (typeof range) {
        case 'string':
            r = safe_decode_range(range);
            break;
        case 'number':
            r = safe_decode_range(sheet["!ref"]);
            r.s.r = range;
            break;
        default:
            r = range;
    }
    if (header > 0) offset = 0;
    var rr = XLSX.utils.encode_row(r.s.r);
    var cols = new Array(r.e.c - r.s.c + 1);
    for (var C = r.s.c; C <= r.e.c; ++C) {
        cols[C] = XLSX.utils.encode_col(C);
        var val = sheet[cols[C] + rr];
        switch (header) {
            case 1:
                hdr.push(C);
                break;
            case 2:
                hdr.push(cols[C]);
                break;
            case 3:
                hdr.push(o.header[C - r.s.c]);
                break;
            default:
                if (val === undefined) continue;
                hdr.push(XLSX.utils.format_cell(val));
        }
    }
    return hdr;
}



function safe_decode_range(range) {
    var o = {s:{c:0,r:0},e:{c:0,r:0}};
    var idx = 0, i = 0, cc = 0;
    var len = range.length;
    for(idx = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if((cc=range.charCodeAt(i)-64) < 1 || cc > 26) break;
        idx = 26*idx + cc;
    }
    o.s.c = --idx;

    for(idx = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if((cc=range.charCodeAt(i)-48) < 0 || cc > 9) break;
        idx = 10*idx + cc;
    }
    o.s.r = --idx;

    if(i === len || range.charCodeAt(++i) === 58) { o.e.c=o.s.c; o.e.r=o.s.r; return o; }

    for(idx = 0; i != len; ++i) {
        if((cc=range.charCodeAt(i)-64) < 1 || cc > 26) break;
        idx = 26*idx + cc;
    }
    o.e.c = --idx;

    for(idx = 0; i != len; ++i) {
        if((cc=range.charCodeAt(i)-48) < 0 || cc > 9) break;
        idx = 10*idx + cc;
    }
    o.e.r = --idx;
    return o;
}
```

Call getHeaders function by passing the Work Sheet will return the headers array of the excel sheet.

Comment: I know SO can fine me for saying thanks, but you are like a boss to me

Comment: it doesn't find the headers until its on row 0, if the headers are row 1, it will just return the text even if they are not headers which is same as default behaviour.

Answer (score 13):

Did the following in xlsx v0.16.9

```
const workbookHeaders = xlsx.readFile(filePath, { sheetRows: 1 });
const columnsArray = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workbookHeaders.Sheets[sheetName], { header: 1 })[0];
```

Comment: I am able to get  header array from this code

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx if we go through the documentation. It says that we need to pass options `By default, sheet_to_json scans the first row and uses the values as headers. With the header: 1 option, the function exports an array of arrays of values.`

So the whole code goes like this:

```
  const data = e.target.result;
  const workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "array" });
  console.log(workbook);
  const firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
  const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName];
  const options = { header: 1 };
  const sheetData2 = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, options);
  const header = sheetData2.shift();
  console.log(header); //you should get your header right here
```

Where `e.target` comes from your input.